# get data in json from url android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to get the data into custom fields:

[image: what I want - 1]

[image: what I want - 2]

I use the following code to get the data in categories that works:

```
List<MusicModel.category> cateList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int j = 0; j < finalobject.getJSONArray("categories").length(); j++ )
{
     MusicModel.category cate = new MusicModel.category();
     cate.setCateTitle(finalobject.getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
     cateList.add(cate);
}
musicModel.setListCategory(cateList);
```

Comment: Whats your problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer blow code :

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(reponseData);
JSONObject postObject = responseObject.optJSONObject("post");
if(null != postObject) {
 JSONObject customFields = postObject.optJSONObject("custom_fields");
 JSONArray postViewCount = customObject.optJSONArray("post_view_count");
 JSONObject postCountObject = postViewCount.get(0);
 String postCount = postCountObject.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but can not run                                                                                    Error:(105, 83) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Add your complete code where you getting these error?